# Outlook Calendar Macro (copy appointments)

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm basically trying to figure out how to create a macro in Outlook that allows me to create an appointment with a specific category, that then copies the appointment from the user's local calendar to an Exchange shared calendar (provided it has the right category).

Does anyone have a bit more insight into the Outlook object model on how this would function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that may help:

```
Sub CreateCalEntry(LeadDate As Date, DueDate As Date, _
        Subject As String, Location As String, Body As String, _
        Optional AddToShared As Boolean = True)
Const olApItem = 1

''This example uses late binding, hence object, rather than the commented
''declarations
Dim apOL As Object ''Outlook.Application
Dim oItem As Object ''Outlook.AppointmentItem '
Dim objFolder As Object ''MAPI Folder


    Set apOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ''This is the folder to copy to:
    Set objFolder = GetFolder("Public Folders/All Public Folders/Shared Calender")
    Set oItem = apOL.CreateItem(olApItem) ''See const, above

    With oItem
        .Subject = Subject
        .Location = Location
        .Body = Body
        .Start = DueDate

        If AddToShared = True Then
            .Move objFolder
        End If

        .Display
    End With

    Set oItem = Nothing
    Set apOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

This allows you to find the shared folder:

```
Public Function GetFolder(strFolderPath As String) As Object 'MAPIFolder
'' strFolderPath needs to be something like
''   "Public Folders\All Public Folders\Company\Sales" or
''   "Personal Folders\Inbox\My Folder"

Dim apOL As Object ''Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Object ''Outlook.NameSpace
Dim colFolders As Object ''Outlook.Folders
Dim objFolder As Object ''Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim arrFolders() As String
Dim i As Long

On Error GoTo TrapError

    strFolderPath = Replace(strFolderPath, "/", "\")
    arrFolders() = Split(strFolderPath, "\")

    Set apOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNS = apOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")


    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.Item(arrFolders(0))

    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrFolders)
            Set colFolders = objFolder.Folders
            Set objFolder = Nothing
            Set objFolder = colFolders.Item(arrFolders(i))

            If objFolder Is Nothing Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

On Error GoTo TrapError

    Set GetFolder = objFolder
    Set colFolders = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set apOL = Nothing

Exit_Proc:
    Exit Function

TrapError:
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: Is there any way to capture the appointment as they input it into the calendar and redirect it?

Comment: It should be possible using Application_ItemSend, but I have not checked.

Comment: Just as an FYI, Application_ItemSend does not work with appointments.